# Create a script that logs terminal inputs with ruby language

Tags: ruby, logging, terminal, scripting

I want to build a ruby on rails application that saves the input from the terminal and the exact time and date, like a logging.

I have searched on the internet but can not find some examples or libraries. Anyone can help me with this one ?

With saving i mean saves to a csv file, like for example you are doing some things on your command like change directory and then use pwd to print working directory. I want to save those commands and the exact time and date that i have done that, to a csv file. If it is possible with columns like command, date, time, result.

Anybody any idea?

Comment: Saves it to where?

Comment: sorry that i didn't answer that, i want to save it to a text file or csv file. i want to log my actions from the terminal with the time and date into a nice csv file with columns like time, data, command, result

Comment: Okay. Please update your question with this information.

Comment: Ruby has lots of logging packages, but until you can better define what you're looking for this is way too open-ended.

Comment: I have edit my post, i hope it is more clear now, Sorry for the misunderstanding